# ¿Como extraer la información de un fixero .log y copiarla en un fixero .txt en Linux?

Tags: linux

Tengo un fixero .log el qual me da información sobre estadisticas de acceso en un servidor i me gustaria poder copiar esta información para almacenarla en un fixero .txt. Existe alguna manera de poder hacer esto? Adicionalmente, me gustaria poder crear una orden en el crontab para poder hacer esta acción de manera diaria i automatica.

Una vez ejecutas el fixero .log se abre una ventana para seleccionar diferentes opciones de visualización:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

I al seleccionar la opción de NCSA Combined Log Format podemos ver:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gràcias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

la forma seria buscar lo que quieres ver por ejempolo
`archivolog.log | grep LaOpcionQueQuieres >> archivo.txt`
el "|grep LaOpcionQueQuieres " es lo que quieres buscar.y con ">>" es la forma de meterlo dentro de otro archivo.
No se si te refieres a esto.